# How to remove duplicate zeroes in multiple rows and columns in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, duplicate

Is there a quick way to remove 0's in multiple cells across columns and rows? I do not just want to delete the 0's but I also want to shift the values up after the 0's have been removed.

I have added sample data below. There's about 100 rows and columns.

```
Column 1 Column 2 Column 3
0        data3    0
data1    0        data5      
data2    data4    0
```

Ideal state after the removal should be:

```
Column 1 Column 2 Column 3
data1    data3    data 5
data2    data4
```

I need to clean the data so I can use it for comparison. Current method I have thought of is just to ignore the 0's by added a IF statement to ignore the zeroes when I do the comparison.

Comment: First three columns only ??

Comment: I have a fair bit of data. Have amended the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Try this short macro:

```
Sub newbie()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim nLastColumn As Long
    Dim nFirstColumn As Long
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, j As Long

    ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    nLastColumn = r.Columns.Count + r.Column - 1
    nFirstColumn = r.Column

    For i = nFirstColumn To nLastColumn
        N = Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
        For j = N To 1 Step -1
            If Cells(j, i).Value = 0 Then
                Cells(j, i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```